# Tried to upload a large file to GitHub using LFS but appeared an error

Tags: python, github, pytorch, git-lfs

I am trying to upload some files that I use from a PyTorch tutorial to model neural networks to my Git repository using LFS. I tried to do this thing but an error appeared so I can't upload these files to the repository.
This is what I did so far:

```
λ git lfs install
Updated Git hooks.
Git LFS initialized.
λ git lfs track "*.tar.gz"
Tracking "*.tar.gz"
λ git lfs track "*.zip"
Tracking "*.zip"
λ git add .gitattributes
λ git push
```

After that, when I tried to push the code to my repository, this error appeared unexpectedly (some of this code is written in German because I'm a student who studies in Germany and my Linux PC is set up in German):

```
Objekte aufzählen: 15, fertig.
Zähle Objekte: 100% (15/15), fertig.
Delta-Kompression verwendet bis zu 4 Threads.
Komprimiere Objekte: 100% (14/14), fertig.
error: RPC fehlgeschlagen; HTTP 401 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 401
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Schreibe Objekte: 100% (14/14), 324.79 MiB | 13.25 MiB/s, fertig.
Gesamt 14 (Delta 1), Wiederverwendet 0 (Delta 0), Pack wiederverwendet 0
fatal: Die Gegenseite hat unerwartet abgebrochen.
Everything up-to-date
```

Can someone find a solution to this problem? I need help!

I tried to upload the files into my GitHub repository and then the error I described earlier happened.